# Using {paginate} in a {parents} pair tag

Tags: relationships, search, pagination, parent, ee7

I'm using EE 7.3.9 have 2 channels related via a relationship field, and I would like to create a page showing all the entries in channel 1 (the parent) that have in common the same field in the channel 2 (the child).

So I created a list with

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="channel2" url_title="{segment_2}" limit="1"}
{parents field="relationship_field" limit="4" paginate="bottom"}
{parents:title}
{paginate}
        <p>Page {current_page} of {total_pages} pages {pagination_links}</p>
{/paginate}
{/parents}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

It shows the first 4 entries that have that particular field in {segment_2}, but the pagination doesn't show.

I also tried to achieve the same result in the other way, accessing via the parent field

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="channel1" search:relationship_field="{segment_2}" limit="4" paginate="bottom"}
```

but it doesn't show anything, and in the documentation there is this statement

> "Relationship fields cannot be searched using the search parameter".

So, how can I achieve the goal to show all the entries that have in common a particular relationship field AND the pagination?

Thank you in advance for your answer.

Comment: Not 100% sure I follow the data setup.. Might be worth giving a quick example of the data your trying to line up.  I am wondering if your looking for the Siblings tag?https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/fieldtypes/relationships.html#accessing-siblings

Answer (score 0):

This might be a good excuse to use a custom query combined with a template embed. In short, you use the query to get a list of entry_ids based on your criteria. Then pass it to the embed template to output and paginate:

First the custom query

```
{!-- get related parent entry IDs for the given child entry --}
{exp:query sql="SELECT parent_id 
               FROM exp_relationships 
               WHERE child_id = 
                 (SELECT entry_id FROM exp_channel_titles WHERE url_title = '{segment_2}' LIMIT 1)"}

    {!-- if it's the first row, set a variable with the entry ID. For subsequent rows, append the ID with a pipe. --}
    {if count == 1}{embed="your_template_group/related_entries" the_ids="{parent_id}"}{if:else}|{parent_id}{/if}
{/exp:query}
```

and the template embed:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="channel1" entry_id="{embed:the_ids}" limit="4" paginate="bottom"}
    {title}
    {paginate}
        <p>Page {current_page} of {total_pages} pages {pagination_links}</p>
    {/paginate}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: Wow, that's a very smart solution, I'd never thought to SQL queries. I tried to implement your code in my page, with these corrections:

{if count == 1}{embed="template_group/related_entries" the_ids="{parent_id}"}{if:else}{embed="template_group/related entries" the_ids="|{parent_id}"}{/if}

and adding dynamic="no" in the embed template.

It shows effectively the entries related to the {segment_2} child (as my code) but.. no pagination. Also, the limit parameter doesn't work with this method, no matter if I put 2 or 4 or whatever I see all the filtered entries.